# Isn't this formula $2\tan^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ invalid when $x^2=1$?

Tags: trigonometry

My book doesn't mention any conditions for this formula, so I was curious what would happen if $x^2$ equals $1$.

Comment: You're right. But usually it's quite obvious so probably your book didn't bother.

Comment: If you are looking for when this formula is valid: it is valid only in $x\in(-1,1)$. For $x=\pm 1$ the RHS is undefined. For $|x|>1$, the LHS and RHS are actually *different* (by $\pm\pi$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The solution is undefined when $x=\pm1$.

Answer (score 1):

The formula may become valid for $x = \pm 1$, if you interpret it in terms of taking the limit as $x \to 1^-$ or $x\to -1^+$. For instance,
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^-}\arctan \left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right) = \arctan (+\infty) = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

$$
\lim_{x\to 1^-} 2 \arctan x = 2 \times \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2}.
$$

Comment: One-sided limit: true. Two-sided limit: definitely not.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes, when $|x| > 1$ the two expressions do not match... they differ by $\pm \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

The claimed identity not only fails when $x^2=1$. It also fails when $x^2>1$. Because the tangent function is not bijective, its inverse is multivalued. In order to maintain the principal branch which is usually defined as the one function value in the real domain, an increment of $\pi$ is needed. The direction of this increment depends on the sign of $x$, thus:

$2\tan^{-1}2=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2(2)}{1-2^2}\right)\color{blue}{+\pi}$

$2\tan^{-1}(-2)=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2(-2)}{1-(-2)^2}\right)\color{blue}{-\pi}.$

Answer (score 0):

Of course! Consider the following equations:

$$\csc^2\theta-\cot^2\theta=1...(i)$$

$$\sec^2\theta-\tan^2\theta=1...(ii)$$

These two are classic trigonometric formulae. However, if $\theta=0^{\circ}$ in (i) and if $\theta=90^{\circ}$ in (ii), then the formulae would become invalid. The case is the same as your queston. Capeesh?